# On GitHub, how to ignore all Dependabot notifications?

Tags: github, notifications, github-issues

On GitHub, how to ignore all `Dependabot` notifications for all projects you follow?

Ideally, how does one ignore all `Dependabot` notifications for all projects, except your own?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76066761/ignore-dependabot-notifications-for-3rd-party-repositories, no solution there at the moment

Comment: @riQQ Thank you for the link.  I added a comment to that QA to reference back here to this older question as well.

Answer (score 0):

On https://github.com/watching, one can select custom, then don't check security alerts. 2 limitations: 1) it needs to be done for each repo 2) there exist security alerts that aren't from dependabot.

[image]

[image]

Note that https://github.com/settings/notifications has some settings for dependabot on the repo one's own.

---

FYI:

- https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-alerts/configuring-notifications-for-dependabot-alerts
- https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/setting-up-notifications/configuring-notifications#filtering-email-notifications

Comment: Thanks Franck. I typically enable Security alerts, so unfortunately, that may be a deal-breaker. What's odd is that I've never seen a `Dependabot` notification show up as a security notification. Specifically, in my GitHub notifications page, there is a `Security alerts` category. That category never has any `Dependabot` notifications. Only on the surface, that experience seems to contradict your recommendation. I still need to read the references you generously provided, so perhaps those will provide further details. If you have further thoughts/ideas, I'm interested in hearing them.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket interesting, maybe my information is incorrect then. I had read somewhere that Dependabot was a type of security alert but the source wasn't that good so that could be incorrect.